# FontAwesome 5 NPM icons issue

Tags: npm, webpack, font-awesome

I'm trying to implement FontAwesome5 to my website with NPM and Webpack. Here is my code:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
import faFacebookF from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/faFacebookF'
import faYoutube from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/faYoutube'
import faInstagram from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/faInstagram'

fontawesome.library.add(faYoutube)
fontawesome.library.add(faFacebookF)
fontawesome.library.add(faInstagram)
```

The situation is: only the first icon added in with `fontawesome.library.add` works and others - not. In this example only Youtube icon is rendered and other looks like that:

[image]

If I just change the order and put Facebook icon to the top like that:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
import faFacebookF from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/faFacebookF'
import faYoutube from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/faYoutube'
import faInstagram from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/faInstagram'

fontawesome.library.add(faFacebookF)
fontawesome.library.add(faYoutube)
fontawesome.library.add(faInstagram)
```

Only Facebook icon will work like that:

[image]

There were no other changes in JS or HTML, just the icons order. If I put ath the top another icon which is not used in my HTML - all 3 icons will be empty.

Could you please help me with this strange issue?

P.S there are no js issues in devtools or in webpack at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As only one pack was in use - 'fontawesome-free-brands' you should use coma separated list like that:

```
fontawesome.library.add(faFacebookF,faYoutube,faInstagram)
```

Comment: Working! Yaaay!